# Update state after the user clicks drop-down menu item

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image: I am building this app.]

The UI has been completed, and I am having trouble setting up the reducers/actions for my app.

My app needs to show the 5 items (picture, name and dropdown name) selected by the user from a dropdown menu that has 100+ items. The items are stored in a file and are used in my app.

As of now, everything is inside one container *items_list* and I have one component for the individual items, *items*.

I want to display the item info when the user clicks an item name from the dropdown.

here is my code so far

**Right now the code displays the UI showed in the picture but the dropdowns do not work yet. What should I do to allow the five items to have their own state? That way I can select an item from an individual dropdown and change only that item info.**

*items_list*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { selectItem } from '../actions/index';
import Item from '../components/item';

class ItemsList extends Component {
  renderItems(item) {
    return (
      <tr key={item.id}>
       <td><Item id={item.id}/></td>
       <td><Item id={item.id}/></td>
       <td><Item id={item.id}/></td>
       <td><Item id={item.id}/></td>
       <td><Item id={item.id}/></td>
      </tr>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Item 1</th>
            <th>Item 2</th>
            <th>Item 3</th>
            <th>Item 4</th>
            <th>Item 5</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.items.map(this.renderItems)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ items }) {
  return { items };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ selectItem }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemsList);
```

*item*

```
import React from 'react';
import {items} from '../../data/items';

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={items[props.id-1].img} />
      <h2>{items[props.id-1].localized_name}</h2>
      <select>
      {items.map((item, id) => 
       <option value="select" key={id}>{item.localized_name}</option>
      )}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

*item_reducer*

```
import { SELECT_ITEM } from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [        {
            "name": "default item",
            "id": 1,
            "localized_name": "No item selected",
            "img": "url link",
            ], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_ITEM:
      return [ action.payload, ...state ];
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: Can you push a small example to github your code seams to be broken anyway.. And the question is not clear.

Comment: @webdeb My question is: what do I have to do if I want each _item_ component (in the pic I showed, an _item_ would be the picture, the name and the dropdown menu) to have their own state ? Example if I click on the drop down of the middle _item_ component and choose let's say item 99 from the dropdown, the picture, name and dropdown will show the item 99.

Comment: @webdeb as for the code, only the dropdown selection doesn't work. I abstracted a lot of information from my code. It's on a private github repo. I can invite you if you want to take a look and try it yourself. Thanks for your time.

Comment: add your logic to it. Whats the problem?

Comment: ok, sure, send the link

Comment: Well, after looking more in detail.. you problem is, that you don't have any references to the actual items, you are not saving the information which item you have choosen for which column. So this part is missing. You have think about it.